# Is Azure EventHub EnqueuedTime monotonically increasing within a partition?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Is Microsoft Azure EventHubs EnqueueTime implemented as a lamport timestamp? ensuring its monotonically increasing within a single partition?

What I'm after is if it is ok to order events by their EnqueuedTime vs SequenceNumber.

This would make it simple to get a partial ordering of all events across partitions with events in correct order within a given partition.

I remember reading the officials docs that Enqueued time can be skewed at small resolutions and that SequenceNumber should be used instead. But i can't remember if it was only for cross partitions. Where this do not make any sense anyway since SequenceNumbers are only unique within a given partition.

Comment: For ordering, I suggest you should add a property which can be used for ordering when sending events, see [Consistency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-availability-and-consistency#consistency).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1203:**

The feedback from support team: The 'enqueuedTime' value represents the actual time of enqueuing the message. And it does not change anything if the events are processed in same server or different server. It only depends on when and which event comes to the event hub first.

---

This is a suggestion rather than directly answer to your question: Is Azure EventHub EnqueuedTime monotonically increasing within a partition? But if you'd like to know this, I can help confirm it with ms support.

For ordering, you can add some properties to the event, like add a sequence number property to indicate the sequence of the event data. Please refer to [Consistency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-availability-and-consistency#consistency) for details, and we use this for ordering / filtering the event data. The sample from the link:

```
var data = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is my message..."));
// Set a custom sequence number property
data.Properties.Add("SequenceNumber", sequenceNumber);
// Send single message async
await eventHubClient.SendAsync(data);
```

Please let me know your concerns.

Comment: I think it can be boiled down to the question: Will `allPartitionsAllEvents.OrderBy(e => e.SystemProperties.EnqueuedTime)` yield a result where events within a partition be ordered such that e1.SequenceNumber < e2.SequenceNumber where e1 comes before e2 in the ordered output of the OrderBy.

Comment: @CodeMonkey, yes, it's correct, I have got feedback from the ms support, please see the updated section of the post about the feedback.

Comment: Thank you for help. I will look for a different solution.